# type Item = &i32 ---> How do I use Item to deref type to i32?

Tags: rust

Let's say there is a `impl<'a> Iterator` where `type Item = &'a i32`.
I would need to get the **not** **ref** type of `Item` like `i32`.
So that I could say instead `Option<T::Item>` (which is in the example `Option<&'a i32>`?) the **`Option<?>`**  which should become **`Option<i32>`**.
Is this possible?

Edit:

@eggyal pointed me to [`<T::Item as std::ops::Deref>::Target`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)

But seems that my use case isn't implemented and would become strange as I'd like to use it with function parameter `values: &[<T::Item as std::ops::Deref>::Target],` and extend a vector `Vec<Vec<<T as Iterator>::Item>>` with these `values` with the result of compile error:

```
the trait `Extend<&<<T as Iterator>::Item as __Deref>::Target>` is not implemented for `Vec<<T as Iterator>::Item>` rustc(E0277)
```

Although I could fix this with adding this `where` to my function

```rust
where
    T::Item: Clone + Copy + std::ops::Deref,
    <T::Item as std::ops::Deref>::Target: Sized,
    Vec<<T as Iterator>::Item>: std::iter::Extend<&'a <<T as Iterator>::Item as std::ops::Deref>::Target>
```

But after some sleep I'll change my `T::Item` type and some more parts of my code which should make this `Deref` unnecessary.

Comment: You could do `<T::Item as std::ops::Deref>::Target`?

Comment: You could deref it with `*` when you get the value. Or use `.copied()` to convert the iterator to be over `i32` instead of `&i32`.

Comment: @PeterHall I'm asking for generic syntax to use `T::Item`.

Comment: @eggyal Becomes somehow ugly: ```where T::Item: Clone + Copy + std::ops::Deref, <T::Item as std::ops::Deref>::Target: Sized,  Vec<<T as Iterator>::Item>: Extend<&<<T as Iterator>::Item as std::ops::Deref>::Target>,```  And in the end the stuff is not living long enough. I think I need to refactor the stuff.

Comment: @eggyal But I think the `as Deref` would be what I've looked for ;-(

Comment: @Markus it would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a more complete example then.